# What DATATYPE should I use when moving data from MySQL to DB2

Tags: java, mysql, db2

I am writing some Java code that is going to read in some data from MySQL and then call a DB2 proc. What would be the difference between these two:

- MySQL:NBR 9.2
- DB2: DECIMAL (9, 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using java.math.BigDecimal

Comment: Given the likelyhood that this is monetarily related, this is pretty much the only answer.